# How to show real-time data in Reactjs from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, reactjs

I have an application the`front-end`is created using `Reactjs` and the `APIs` are created using `erlang`, and currently I am using `MySQL database` in this application. In this `database` the data gets added & updated at any like to show `online offline`users ,Now my question is how can I get `real-time data` in frontend without refreshing my `application`. There may be more than `10k` users saved in my `database` and messages of these users

Comment: Read more about [socket](https://socket.io/).

Comment: Create socketio api and its all easy, check this: https://codeforgeek.com/real-time-app-socket-io/

Answer (score 0):

Since your app's frontend was built with ReactJS, it works as an SPA. One of the major perks of SPAs is that they let you update parts of your app without needing to refresh the page, so you should already be able to do that. As for getting messages communicated to the desired clients in real-time, you can use websockets for that.

Comment: Yusuf: is it a good idea to load all the users in redux store from database

Comment: I would say no because anyone can then view user information on the frontend, you should never put sensitive data on the frontend. Besides loading that many users will likely slow down your app significantly.